# Share data between tvOS app and Top Shelf Extension

Tags: swift3, tvos

How do you share data between tvOS app and its Top Shelf Extension? I want to save some user settings from within the app and make them available to the Top Shelf Extension so I can tailor the top shelf items accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: put your application and your extension (here the TopShelf estension) inside the same app-group.

You will find a lot of explanation on this issue within the documentation:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html
- https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH26-SW61